# How to pass Bidirectional LSTM state to earlier LSTM layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to do a seq2seq model with and encoder LSTM and decoder LSTM, both with `Bidirectional` layers.

I can pass the hidden state and memory cell forward to the decoder LSTM, but I can't see how I'd possibly pass the values back from the decoder to the encoder.

```
def sequence_model(total_words, emb_dimension, lstm_units):
    # Encoder
    encoder_input = Input(shape=(None,), name="Enc_Input")
    x = Embedding(total_words, emb_dimension, input_length=max_sequence_length, name="Enc_Embedding")(encoder_input)
    x, state_h, state_c, _, _ = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_units, return_state=True, name="Enc_LSTM1"), name="Enc_Bi1")(x) # pass hidden activation and memory cell states forward
    encoder_states = [state_h, state_c] # package states to pass to decoder
    
    # Decoder
    decoder_input = Input(shape=(None,), name="Dec_Input")
    x = Embedding(total_words, emb_dimension, name="Dec_Embedding")(decoder_input)
    x = LSTM(lstm_units, return_sequences=True, name="Dec_LSTM1")(x, initial_state=encoder_states)
    decoder_output = Dense(total_words, activation="softmax", name="Dec_Softmax")(x)

    func_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[encoder_input,decoder_input], outputs=decoder_output)
    return func_model
```

The forward states are passed to the `initial_state` of the decoder LSTM layer. But if I wrap this `Dec_LSTM1` layer with a `Bidirectional` Layer, it doesn't like me passing the `initial_state` value in and breaks.

Am I right in thinking I don't need the backwards states from the encoder LSTM layer?

Attached is an image of the architecture I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code is breaking when you add `Bidirectional` to your decoder because you have left out two elements from the encoder state.

```py
x, state_h, state_c, _, _ = ...
#                    ^  ^
# -------------------|--|
```

An LSTM state has two tensors in it, of shape `(batch, hidden)`; when you run your
LSTM in both directions, this will add two more states (the backward pass).

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense


enc_in = Input(shape=(None,))
enc_x = Embedding(1024, 128, input_length=92)(enc_in)

# vanilla LSTM
s_enc_x, *s_enc_state = LSTM(256, return_state=True)(enc_x)

print(len(s_enc_state))
print(s_enc_state)
# 2
# [<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 256) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'lstm_7')>,
#  <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 256) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'lstm_7')>]

# bi-directional LSTM
bi_enc_x, *bi_enc_state = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_state=True))(enc_x)

print(len(bi_enc_state))
print(bi_enc_state)
# 4
# [<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 256) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'bidirectional_6')>,
#  <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 256) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'bidirectional_6')>,
#  <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 256) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'bidirectional_6')>,
#  <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 256) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'bidirectional_6')>]

# decoder
dec_in = Input(shape=(None,))
dec_x = Embedding(1024, 128, input_length=92)(dec_in)
dec_x = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(
    dec_x, initial_state=bi_enc_state)  # <= use bidirectional state
output = Dense(1024, activation="softmax")(dec_x)

print(output.shape)
# TensorShape([None, None, 1024])
```

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the solution, but it seems really counter intuitive. I thought the two variables from that Bidirectional layer that I wasn't using would be the states passed to the left of my encoder section, therefore weren't needed. I thought I would need to pass fwd states from my first bidirectional layer to the 2nd bidirectional layer, and bwd states from the 2nd bidirectional layer to the first bidirectional layer.